# How can I change the filename of release files in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

I need help. I've created a new release of my tool in GitLab and the zip files were created successfully. I can now download them via this URL:

`https://gitlab.xxx.de/xxx-development/xxx-helper/-/archive/v1.0.0/xxx-helper-v1.0.0.zip`

The problem is that I need to remove the `-v1.0.0` somehow from the file name of the zip file because otherwise a target system creates a folder with the version in the name which makes huge problems. So at least I need this structure:

`https://gitlab.xxx.de/xxx-development/xxx-helper/-/archive/v1.0.0/xxx-helper.zip`

How can I do this?

Comment: From the URL I'm guessing self hosted Gitlab? It seems like you're referencing the branch/tag from the path (`/v1.0.0/`) that is included in the filename (`-v1.0.0.`) provided in the "download button" of a given project.  Can you confirm that you're asking about the "Download source code" functionality?  If not, please provide more direction on what you are trying to accomplish - and how..

Comment: When I create a new release in my self hosted GitLab and I open the release, I can see multiple archives I can download like .zip, .tar.gz .... thats what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The naming of releases is automated, and changing it would require updates to several parts of the Gitlab stack/codebase.

Answer: it's technically possible but not simple.

One portion that serves as a functional example to illustrate; guest users of private projects are allowed to view the Releases page but are not allowed to view details about the Git repository (in particular, tag names). Because of this, release titles are replaced with a generic title like “Release-1234” for Guest users to avoid leaking tag name information.

This is the URL you are referring to, and asking to change.  It uses the generic title.

I can point to some parts of the codebase, but probably not all easily - it would require some significant effort.  This is a project.  It would also matter if you are using CE or EE.